# What meaning does the following sine wave have when it comes to amplitude?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, simulation, matlab

So I am getting into engineering and was curious what it means when a sine wave isn't even in a sense, at 0, from my understanding, the waveform has  peak to peak amplitude of 4, while having a positive peak of 3 and negative peak of 1, does it mean anything in specific when it isn't even at a positive peak of 2 and negative peak of 2?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It means that there is a positive offset of one. So your signal is

$$ x(t) = 1 + 2 \cdot \sin(\omega t)$$

where:

- 1 is the offset
- 2 is the amplitude of your signal (not 4).

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, thanks for the clarification